# Send indexPath.row to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, navigationcontroller

So I have the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method into a **UITableViewController**.

The TableView goes to a **UIViewController** which is controlled by a **NavigationController**.

I want to **send the indexPath.row** to the class called by the NavigationController, is there any way to **send a parameter to another class**?

My app scheme is:

TabBarController ---> NavigationController ---> TableViewController ---> UIViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboard:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

else

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        YourViewController *vc = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
        [vc setIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using storyboard: where I have to call the prepareForSegue method? I guess in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: And.. the UIViewController that I call in the initWithNibName is not a TableViewControll so it doesnt have a setIndexPath selector..

Comment: You don't need to call prepareForSegue, if you drag segue from your tableViewCell in storyboard to your viewController, you have to name it @"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE", and after that when user tap cell, the prepareForSegue method is called. If you want to pass data you need to have some @property in your UIViewController for example NSIndexPath, or NSInteger row, and when you're passing just set property [vc setRow:indexPath.row];